# Can I edit an excel file on onedrive using python?

Tags: python, excel, onedrive

I have been searching for hours trying to find out how I could edit an Excel file saved to OneDrive using python and have had no luck. Help if you know how/if it is possible.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

@JeremiahTrest Welcome to Stackoverflow. I don't think that's how OneDrive works. What I mean is, I don't think it's possible to directly edit a file that is saved to your OneDrive in the cloud with any language. What you would have to do is to get a copy of the file on the machine that is running the Python script, update the file on that machine and save it with the changes, then push the changed file to your OneDrive. I looked and found [this SDK](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python) for Python that is meant to be able to help you interface with the OneDrive API. So, you would use this SDK to get the file from OneDrive, update the file locally, then use the SDK to push the changed file back out to OneDrive.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post as I have the same task. Here's what I'm going to try:
Use the request library on python to call the OneDrive API.
Here's the page on excel APIs:
[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/excel?view=graph-rest-1.0)

I'll update when I have my code.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31303156)