# How do I edit an online xlsx file in python?

Tags: python, selenium, xlsx, openxlsx, webbot

I need to edit this file with any python module:
https://1drv.ms/x/s!Aq2lKlhSyqf5mjiC6CYkC1QGXNSy?e=Wh88AT
but I don't want to download it edit and then upload again. I tried using webbot, but I couldn't even find the 'editing mode' button.

```
import time
from time import sleep
from webbot import Browser
driver = Browser()
driver.new_tab(url='https://1drv.ms/x/s!Aq2lKlhSyqf5mjiC6CYkC1QGXNSy?e=Wh88AT')
driver.switch_to_tab(1)
driver.close_current_tab()
print("waiting...")
sleep(20)
print("start")
driver.click(classname = 'list-349' , tag = 'button' )
```

but it returns this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 19, in <module>
    driver.click(classname = 'list-349' , tag = 'button' )
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/webbot/webbot.py", line 466, in click
    maxElements = self.__find_element(text, tag, classname, id, number, css_selector, xpath, loose_match)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/webbot/webbot.py", line 294, in __find_element
    element_fetch_helper(("//body//{}".format(tag)), score=50)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/webbot/webbot.py", line 202, in element_fetch_helper
    add_to_init_text_matches_score(self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath), score)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 410, in find_elements_by_xpath
    return self.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1005, in find_elements
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENTS, {
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.101)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.39.562737 (dba483cee6a5f15e2e2d73df16968ab10b38a2bf),platform=Linux 5.15.0-1012-gcp x86_64)
```

I'm using replit by the way.

Comment: Hope the API can help you. [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/excel?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: What python API can I use and how to use it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63223648/can-i-edit-an-excel-file-on-onedrive-using-python