# How to access and edit Excel files on One Drive using python

Tags: python, excel, onedrive

I am trying to create a UI that edits an excel sheet saved online in OneDrive. I do not own the excel sheet so it cant be downloaded. I have tried a few methods but cannot seem to find a good solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Try looking at [Can I edit an excel file on onedrive using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63223648/can-i-edit-an-excel-file-on-onedrive-using-python)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.